# Trouble with jQuery .ajax and DataSnap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, delphi, datasnap

I have one simple DataSnap server and i having trouble consuming the Json data on .ajax function by JQuery.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:53383/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/logo",
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json",
                  "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
                  "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 1 Oct 1990 05:00:00 GMT",
                  "Pragma": "dssession="+pragma,
                  "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46MTIz"},
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
       });
```

The function works, but when i send headers for the DataSnap authentication ("Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46MTIz") JQuery make two requets, one 401 (Not authorised) and other ok. How this happend? I make one only request.

Answer (score 1):

Try requesting Auth before actually sending a request:

```
beforeSend: function(req) {
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46MTIz");
}
```

I'm not sure if this solves the problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks by answering question, but don't works. The same problem happens. :(